# The property of a weakly convergent sequence in $\ell_p$-2

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

> Prove that $\forall x\in l_p$, $1\leq p<\infty$ and $\forall y_n\rightharpoonup0$ in $l_p$ holds equality $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup}\|x+y_n\|^p=\|x\|^p+\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup}\|y_n\|^p$.

Unfortunately, I have no attempt to solve, because I don’t even understand where to start. I ask for any help.

I know that a weakly convergent sequence is bounded, so it can be argued that there is a limsup exists. I know the definition of weak convergence ($y_n\rightharpoonup0$ means $\forall\varphi\in l_p^\ast$ $\varphi(y_n)\to0$) and that weak convergence in $l_p$ implies coordinatewise.

Comment: I suggest that you add the meaning of the relevant definitions to the question. You could also try to solve the question special cases for $x$ and $y_n$. You could also add some of your mathematical knowledge about the objects that appear in the question, if you think that they could be relevant. For example: what do you know about weakly converging sequences?

Comment: As for special cases: pick any $x$ and any sequence $y_n$ with $y_n \rightharpoonup 0$ that comes to your mind and try to solve the question for this example. For example, you could use $x=(2,1,0,0,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: Hmm, for example, $y_n=(0,0,...,0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...)$ (where $n-1$ zeroes) is weakly-null in $l_2$, and for suggested $x$ there is $\|x+y_n\|^2=\|x\|^2+\|y_n\|^2$. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt. Any indication will be appreciated.

$$y_n\rightharpoonup0 \Rightarrow \,\forall k:\,\,<y_n,e_k>\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$ (Since $e_k \in {l_p}^* = l_q $ , $q$ is conjugate index of $p$)

Also, since $c_{00} = \{\vec{a}: a(n)\in F\text{, number of nonzero element is finite}\}$ dense in $(l_p,\|\cdot\|_{l_p})$, there is $(x_m) \in c_{00}$ such that $\,x_m \rightarrow x \,\,\text{ in } \,\,(l_p,\|\cdot\|_{l_p})$.

Now, you can easily verify (like in your comment) followings. (for all m)

$$
\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup}\,{\|x_m+y_n\|}
^p = {\|x_m\|}^p+\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup}\,{\|y_n\|}^p\,\,\text{ - (1)}
$$

Moreover, by operating ' $\underset{m\to\infty}{\lim\sup} \,\, \underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup}$'   on following inequality you can get $\underset{m\to\infty}{\lim\sup} \,\, \underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup}{\,\|x_m+y_n\|} = \underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup}{\|x+y_n\|}$ - (2).
$$
-{\|x_m - x\|}\leq{\|x_m+y_n\|}-{\|x+y_n\|}\leq{\|x_m - x\|}
$$

Then from (2), $\underset{m\to\infty}{\lim\sup} \,\, \underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup}{\,\|x_m+y_n\|}^p = \underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup}{\|x+y_n\|}^p$ - (3)  is also true.

Finally, using (3) on $\underset{m\to\infty}{\lim\sup}$ (1) will give your equality.

---

### Addendum

First, there is $N$ such that $k>N \Rightarrow x_m (k) = 0$.

for $\epsilon'>0$, there is $N'$ such that $$n>N' \Rightarrow |y_n(k)| < \epsilon = \frac{1}{2} \min[\epsilon'/N^{1/p} ,pN(2\|x_m\|_{sup})^{1-p} ,\|x_m\|_{sup}]  \, , \forall k\leq N$$

then, for $n>N'$ (N is fixed),
$$
\Bigg|\|x_m+y_n\|^p - (\|x_m\|^p + \|y_n\|^p) \Bigg| \\= \Bigg|\sum_{k\leq N} |x_m(k) + y_n(k)|^p + \sum_{k > N} | y_n(k)|^p  - \sum_{} |x_m(k)|^p - \sum | y_n(k)|^p \Bigg| \\= \Bigg|\sum_{k\leq N} (|x_m(k) + y_n(k)|^p - |x_m(k)|^p) - \sum_{k \leq N} | y_n(k)|^p  \Bigg|\\ \leq  pN\epsilon (\|x_m\|_{sup} + \epsilon)^{p-1} + N\epsilon^p \text{ (MVT used for first part) }\\<\epsilon'
$$
Thus
$$
\|x_m+y_n\|^p  < \|x_m\|^p + \|y_n\|^p + \epsilon' \quad\forall n>N'\\ $$
by '$\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup}$' on each side,
$$
\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup}\,\|x_m+y_n\|^p  < \|x_m\|^p + \underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup}\,\|y_n\|^p + \epsilon'.
$$

Since $\epsilon'$ is arbitrary, $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup}\,\|x_m+y_n\|^p  \leq \|x_m\|^p + \underset{n\to\infty}{\lim\sup}\,\|y_n\|^p$.

Another inequality ($\geq$) is almost same.

---

Want: $({\lim\sup}\,{a_n})^p = {\lim\sup}\,{a_n}^p$,  when $p>0$ and $a_n \geq 0\\$.

First, from definition of limsup,
$$
({\lim\sup}\,{a_n})^p = (\underset{n}{\inf}\,[{\sup}\,\{x_k \,:\, k\geq n \}])^p
$$
Since $x \mapsto x^p$ is **continuous** and monotonically increasing function on $x\geq0$,

(Actually, there is the case for ${\sup}\,\{a_k \,:\, k\geq n \} = \infty$ , but it is easier to show $\infty = \infty$ of WANT.)
$$
=\underset{n}{\inf}\,[{\sup}\,\{a_k \,:\, k\geq n \}]^p
$$
Again, by same reason,
$$
=\underset{n}{\inf}\,[{\sup}\,\{a_k^p \,:\, k\geq n \}]
$$
Indeed,
$$
={\lim\sup}\,{a_n}^p  \quad\text{(By definition)}
$$

All you have to show now is (and same for $\inf$)

$$ \sup f(a_n) = f [ \sup a_n ]$$

where $f$: **continuous** and mono. increasing.

For convenience, let $\alpha = \sup a_n$. 
(case of $\alpha = \infty$ needs slightly different argument, but not the case of ours.)

since $a_n \leq \alpha$ for all $n$, $f(a_n) \leq f(\alpha)$ , thus $f(\alpha)$ is upper bound for $\{f(a_n)\}$ .

Thus $\boldsymbol{f(\alpha) \geq \sup f(a_n)}$.

For another inequality, enough to show $f(\alpha) < \sup f(a_n) + \epsilon$, for arbitrary $\epsilon >0$.

Since $f$ is continuous at $x = \alpha$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|\alpha - x|<\delta$ implies $|f(\alpha) - f(x) | <\epsilon$ .

Also, since $\alpha = \sup a_n$, there is $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_m + \delta > \alpha$. Thus,  $|f(\alpha) - f(a_m) | <\epsilon$.

i.e.
$$
f(\alpha)<\epsilon + f(a_m)\, ,\,\, \boldsymbol{f(\alpha)<\epsilon + \sup f(a_n)}.
$$

Comment: I found serious mistake on $-{\|x_m - x\|}^p\leq{\|x_m+y_n\|}^p-{\|x+y_n\|}^p\leq{\|x_m - x\|}^p$. Answer will be editted in a minute.

Comment: Thank you for solution. I'll try to figure it out and then I will accept the answer.

Comment: @thing I added some argument for your later comment. (Sorry for late) If there is another unclear part on my solution, please let me know

Comment: What I wrote in the previous comments, I realized myself, thanks. One thing left that I didn’t understand: why if $\lim\sup a_n=a$ we have $\lim\sup a_n^p=a^p$? Maybe this is some well-known property of the upper limit, which is not familiar to me?

Comment: yeap, that is true for p>0 (obviously, case of p=0 also) and $a_n \geq 0 $. I will give you a simple explanation for that. (editing)

Comment: sorry, haven't been noticed , continuous condition was needed. But now proof is valid.

Comment: Thank you very much. You really helped!

Comment: Your welcome :)