# Show $\limsup||y+y_n||= ||y||_p^p + \limsup||y_n||_p^p$ for $y \in {\ell}^p$ $y_n \rightarrow 0$ weakly

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose $y$ and {$y_n$}$_1^\infty$ $\in \ell^p$  s.t: $1 \leq p<\infty$, $y_n \rightarrow 0$ weakly.

Show:

$$\limsup||y_n+y||_p^p=||y||_p^p + \limsup||y_n||_p^p$$

The hint I'm given is to ''First assume $y$ has finite support''.

Attempting to follow the hint: suppose $y$ is supported on $\{1...N\}$.

Then we can write:

$$\limsup||y+y_n||_p^p=\limsup \sum_{i=1}^\infty |y_i+y_{n_i}|^p=\limsup( \sum_{i=1}^N|y_i+y_{n_i}|^p + \sum_{i=N+1}^\infty |y_{n_i}|^p)$$ = $$\limsup (\sum_1^N|y_{n_i}+y_i|^p - \sum_{i=1}^N |y_{n_i}|^p + ||y_{n_i}||_p^p)$$ 
Here I'm stuck. I cannot even imagine how I can use the weak convergence of $y_n$. It almost feels like I'm missing a basic property of summations. I can't seem to manipulate the first two terms at all.

EDIT: Using that $y_{n_i} \rightarrow 0$ I think I can say:

$$\limsup( \sum_{i=1}^N|y_i+y_{n_i}|^p + \sum_{i=N+1}^\infty |y_{n_i}|^p) \leq \limsup \sum_1^N |y_{n_i}+y_n|^p + \limsup||y_n||_p^p=\\  \limsup \sum_1^N |y_i|^p +  \limsup||y_n||_p^p = ||y||_p^p +  \limsup||y_n||_p^p$$

Extending this to a general $\ell^p$ vector is still very mysterious to me.

Comment: Your application of Minkowski's inequality is not correct.

Comment: Why? My understanding is that it is the triangle inequality for p-norms. Does the p-power make it false?

Comment: Exactly. The inequality fails when you take the $p-$ th powers. Take $p=2$ to see easily why it fails.

Comment: In $\ell^p$, weak convergence implies coordinatewise converge. This should be helpful here.

Comment: To be certain, by ''coordinate wise'' ; you're saying that if $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$ then $x_{n_i}$ converges to $x_i$? (assuming $x, x_n \in \ell^p$ of course)

Comment: See answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536700/the-property-of-a-weakly-convergent-sequence-in-ell-p-2